# ASP.NET IIS 7.5 Error, Access Denied

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5

We recently moved an ASP application from running on an IIS 6.0 web instance to a separate IIS 7.5 instance.  When we invoke one of the functions that does PDF file manipulation and then emails the file we get the following error and we are unsure how to resolve:

**Server Error in '/' Application.**

---

**Access is denied.**

**Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details:** System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied.

ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request identity. ASP.NET has a base process identity (typically {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6) that is used if the application is not impersonating. If the application is impersonating via , the identity will be the anonymous user (typically IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated request user.

To grant ASP.NET access to a file, right-click the file in Explorer, choose "Properties" and select the Security tab. Click "Add" to add the appropriate user or group. Highlight the ASP.NET account, and check the boxes for the desired access.

**Source Error:**

```
[No relevant source lines]
```

**Source File:** c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\284fd53e\989a1e10\App_Web_2wpmcxaa.3.cs    Line: 0

**Stack Trace:**

```
[UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied.
]

    [TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
       System.RuntimeType.InvokeDispMethod(String name, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Object target, Object[] args, Boolean[] byrefModifiers, Int32 culture, String[] namedParameters) +0
       System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams) +337
       System.Type.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture) +36
       System.Web.Mail.LateBoundAccessHelper.CallMethod(Type type, Object obj, String methodName, Object[] args) +66
       System.Web.Mail.LateBoundAccessHelper.CallMethod(Object obj, String methodName, Object[] args) +49

[HttpException (0x80004005): Access is denied.
]
   System.Web.Mail.LateBoundAccessHelper.CallMethod(Object obj, String methodName, Object[] args) +99
   System.Web.Mail.CdoSysHelper.Send(MailMessage message) +1738
   System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail.Send(MailMessage message) +273
   Nps.PayrollPlus.NpsPage.Page_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e) +660
   System.Web.UI.TemplateControl.OnError(EventArgs e) +8781802
   System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e) +84
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +6776
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +242
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() +80
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context) +21
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +49
   ASP.rms009_reportdist_rddist_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\284fd53e\989a1e10\App_Web_2wpmcxaa.3.cs:0
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +181
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously
```

Answer (score 1):

Under permission menu(placed usually in right side) in your IIS server configuration , add everyone or Anonymous Authentication and your error will be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Try Enabling the Anonymous Authentication of your Site folder . I too had the same problem and it worked for me .

Comment: Hi Reshma, thanks for this.  We will try this and test and let you know results...  Do you have any specific details on what steps to take?

Comment: Site --> Authentication --> Anonymous Authentication --> Enable  .. Also you can edit your Anonymous Authentication to Specific user or Application pool identity

Comment: @shwashbuckle you can add Anonymous Authentication or Everyone , both will serve the same.

Comment: My anonymous Authentication is in Specific User with Username IUSR @shwashbuckle

Comment: After furrther investigation it looks like it could be related to us not having CDO permissions set correctly.  See: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mist/2015/10/12/things-to-check-when-a-cdo-mail-enabled-classic-asp-site-is-not-sending-mail-after-a-migration-to-iis7/ and http://forums.iis.net/t/1164349.aspx?Sending+e+mail+with+classic+ASP+SMTP+server+and+IIS7+5

Comment: Reshma R and I already told that you need to manually change the permission or add everyone/anonymous to it.

Comment: Yes.. We both suggested the same thing to you .